# how do i import compass framework in exiting bootstrap template?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, compass-sass, scss-mixins

I've installed Compass Framework in Bootstrap 4 in an existing project, but its giving an error, 'import not found' or 'file unreadable'. What is the proper way to install Compass on an existing Bootstrap 4 template?

```
"status": 1,
  "file": "/Users/chetandhargalkar/Documents/medino/assets/sass/main.scss",
  "line": 5,
  "column": 1,
  "message": "File to import not found or unreadable: compass.",
  "formatted": "Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.\n        on line 5 of assets/sass/main.scss\n>> @import 'compass';\n\n   ^\n"
}
```

Comment: Do you really need Compass in your project? It's totally outdated and haven't been supported for 3-4 years (it's a developers team decision)

Comment: Maybe it's better to use Bourbon https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon, it's more modern and supported?

Comment: i am working on bootstrap4 template.i had download template from net and wen i tried compiling its giving error .is there any way to make work ?

Comment: it doesn't work even without compass?